# Retrieve player rank with google play games

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, rank

I would like to know if is it possible to retrieve rank of the actual player, in a leaderboard data?

I want to do this for a custom leaderboard UI.

I'm using unity and the google play games

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to obtain the rank with the [official](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) google-play-games SDK if that's what you are using.

With Unity's [`Social`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html) API, you can obtain the player's rank with [`IScore.rank`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.IScore-rank.html). First, load the scores with [`Social.LoadScores`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.LoadScores.html) which gives you array of [`IScore`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.IScore.html). Loop over it and compare the [`IScore.userID`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.IScore-userID.html) until you find the user id you want to get the rank for then get the `IScore.rank`.

```
void GetUserRank(string user, Action<int> rank)
{
    Social.LoadScores("Leaderboard01", scores =>
    {
        if (scores.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Retrieved " + scores.Length + " scores");

            //Filter the score with the user name
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                if (user == scores[i].userID)
                {
                    rank(scores[i].rank);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Failed to retrieved score");
    });
}
```

**Usage**:

```
int rank = 0;
GetUserRank("John", (status) => { rank = status; });
Debug.Log("John's rank is: " + rank);
```

Or

```
string id = Social.localUser.id;
//string id = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id;
int rank = 0;
GetUserRank(id, (status) => { rank = status; });
Debug.Log(id + "'s rank is: " + rank);
```

Of course, you will have to do some authentication stuff because you can o this.